# Convert jquery function into javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to use javascript for below mention work which is done in jquery and working perfect. Reason to use javascript is to know how it can be done with javascript.I google it but not find any clue to how get it done

http://jsfiddle.net/2vP24/

```
$('.first').find('.sub1').next().css('background','#ff0000')
```

Comment: get jQuery source and work it out, will take some time :)

Answer (score 2):

You won't find a solution for exactly that line of code if that's what you were looking for. If you dig into the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) you'll eventually figure out what you need, but here's a way, assuming there's only one `.sub1` inside each `.first`.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.first');

[].forEach.call(els, function(el) {
  var next = el.querySelector('.sub1').nextSibling;
  next.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
});
```

Comment: No, IE9+ only. If you want older browser I'd stick to jQuery instead of the otherwise ugly code you'll have to write...But I'll leave that up to you, you have the link to the docs and some code to work with.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about supporting older browsers, this should do the same thing:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.first .sub1 + *'), function(elem) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
});
```